# JSON dinâmico e popular DataTable

Tags: json, datatable

estou com problemas a gerar uma mensagem JSON dinamicamente e popular um DataTable.

Quando faço da seguinte forma funciona:

```
var dataSet = [
   [ “1”, “01/10/2018”, “200,00” ],
   [ “2”, “01/11/2018”, “250,00” ],
   [ “3”, “01/12/2018”, “350,00” ]
];

$(’#teste’).DataTable({
   //paging: false,
   //searching: false,
   retrieve: true,
   destroy: true,
   data: dataSet,
   columns: [
     { title: “id” },
     { title: “Data” },
     { title: “Valor” }
   ]
});
```

Quando tento gerar dinamicamente, não funciona.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dados.length - 1; i++){

   p = “[ “” + (i+1) + “”,”;
   d = “”" + dados[i] + “”,";
   v = “”" + vlr + “” ]";
   msgJson = msgJson + p + d + v + “,”;

}

dataSet = msgJson.substr(0,msgJson.length-1);
```

Mensagem msgJson gerada:

```
[ “1”,“11/10/2018”,“30” ],[ “2”,“11/11/2018”,“30” ],[ “3”,“11/12/2018”,“30” ]
```

Alguma luz?

Comment: Creio que a sintaxe assim `p = "["" + (i+1)...`  pode ocasionar problema. Escreva distinguindo aspas duplas e simples assim `p = '[""+ (i+1)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de criar uma string e depois transformar em arrray, melhor criar um array e ir adicionando os itens.

```
  var dataSet = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < dados.length - 1; i++){
    var p = String(i+1);
    var d = String(dados[i]);
    var v = String(vlr)

    var item = [p, d, v];
    dataSet.push(item)
  }
```

Comment: var dataSet = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < dados.length - 1; i++){
            var p = String(i+1);
            var d = String(dados[i]);
            var v = String(vlr)

            var item = [p, d, v];
            dataSet.push(item)
         }    
    
obrigado pelo help, mas como jogo para o dataTable?

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou!

```
      var dataSet = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < dados.length - 1; i++){
        var p = String(i+1);
        var d = String(dados[i]);
        var v = String(vlr)

        var item = [p, d, v];
        dataSet.push(item)
     }                                                 

     $('#tblParcelas').DataTable({
        //paging: false,
        //searching: false,
        //retrieve: true,           
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
          { title: "Parcela" },
          { title: "Data Vencimento" },            
          { title: "Valor" }
          ]
     });
```